# SharePoint Online - JSON Column Formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a List Lookup in my form. This gives the user the ability to choose multiple unique values.

The problem I am having is that the values are being translated back on to the SharePoint list with `[ID]";#"[Unique Value]`. The ID can be up to 4 digits long.

Below is an example of what I see in the SharePoint list. **I'd like to format the column with JSON to remove the [ID] and "#"**.

Example of list:

`1275;#Family Information;#1245;#Education and Skills`

Example of what I would like to see:

`Family Information; Education and Skills`

Thank you!

Comment: What's the type of that column??

Comment: Please share some screenshots about the parent list and the column.

Comment: I'm using a Multi Lines of Text Column type.